# android NFC can't read RIFD

Tags: android, rfid

We have RIFD chip for entry to work. And try create application for entry. And i have problem with read RIFD chip. We use RFID chip type EM Marin 4102. And my mobile phone (samsung s6) can't see this chip if although empty. 
Do you know what is problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Not all RFID chips and reader are compatible.

Comment: NFC using a frequency of 13.56Mhz, but most RFID entrance system using  frequency from 125khz to 150khz

Comment: news There is some number load on this chip from production...